# How to say "to encourage."

Tags: grammar

I've been looking various ways to say encourage but it seems to be a bit tricky in Japanese. I want to use it in this way:

"Don't encourage him to jump off that rock."
"I encouraged him to apply to his dream school."

This is why I currently have for a solution, correct me if I am wrong.

"その岩から跳ぶように激励するな”
”志望校に受験するようにお勧めした”（激励した？）（励ました?)

Comment: Try [促す](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%BF%83%E3%81%99).

Comment: I think some more context would help, especially for the first one. Does he want to jump? Why does he need any encouragement? Who might give it and who is the one trying to stop that, and why?

Comment: Yes, it is tricky because the usage of word "encourage" spans the realms of several different expressions in Japanese. We need context to choose the suitable one.